# Shortcut to switch to physical keyboard layouts

Tags: keyboard, android-emulator, external-keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I use Android Emulator on MacBook Pro M1.
I have trouble with a physical keyboard which works in a very odd way as it doesn't change the layout with `ctrl` + `space` and any other combinations. So I need to go to **System -> Languages & Input -> Physical keyboard -> qwerty2** each time.

Is it possible to add a switch to GBoard or the bottom menu to toggle the physical keyboard layouts?